# How do I install pydasm?

Tags: python, installation, traceback

I need help installing pydasm into python 2.7. The readme.txt file tells me that I have to enter **python setup.py build_ext** into the cli. When I do, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    raise DistutilsPlatformError()
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError
```

If you can help, please let me know!

Comment: The link you mentioned is out of date and you will get a 404.
Use this Link instead: https://github.com/axcheron/pydasm
Works on Kali Linux 2019 fine.
Just download the git repo. `cd pydasm` `python setup.py install` Easy ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one answered my question, I thought I would so if other people have the same issue they can look here for help.

I went to this site: http://ademata.blogspot.com/2010/07/installing-pydasm-and-pefile-module-on.html

Follow these instructions:

Pydasm is included with the module libdasm. An open source fork is available at http://libdasm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ svn/libdasm-read-only and requires the use of the subversion tool. To install subversion use sudo apt-get install subversion.

Run the following command to download the latest libdasm code:
svn checkout http://libdasm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ svn/libdasm-read-only

Run the following series of commands to install the module on python:

```
cd svn/libdasm-read-only/
```

`make`

```
sudo make install
```

`cd pydasm`

```
sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev
```

(use the most recent, so for me I did 2.7)

`python setup.py build_ext`

`sudo python setup.py install`

Pefile is included in Ubuntu's repository, to install the pefile module run sudo apt-get install python-pefile.

Hope this helped.

Comment: If you just need pydasm, there is no need to do the ```make``` and ```make install``` for libdasm. The ```python setup.py build_ext``` will take care of compiling the libdasm library and including it in the python module.